# Error, this.refs.inputLogin.value undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a login screen, I did all the authentication logic, but I came across the following error:
TypeError: It is not possible to read the 'value' property of indefinite.

I don't understand, when seeing me it's all right, I did this same logic in another project and it worked.

I don't know how to proceed, I've already reworded the page twice, please, I need help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './loginPage.css'




class Login extends Component   {


    fazerLogin = infosDoEvento => {
        infosDoEvento.preventDefault();
        const dadosDeLogin = {
        login: this.inputLogin.value,
        senha: this.inputSenha.value
        };
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/usuarios", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dadosDeLogin)
        })
        .then(async responseDoServer => {
        if (!responseDoServer.ok) {
        const respostaDeErroDoServidor = await responseDoServer.json();
        const errorObj = Error(respostaDeErroDoServidor.message);
        errorObj.status = responseDoServer.status;
        throw errorObj;
        }
        return responseDoServer.json();
        })
        .then(dadosDoServidorEmObj => {
        const token = dadosDoServidorEmObj.token;
        if (token) {
        localStorage.setItem("TOKEN", token);
        this.props.history.push("/");
        }
        })
        .catch(err => {
        console.error(`[Erro ${err.status}]`, err.message);
        });

    }


    render() {
        return (
           
            <div className="loginPage">
                <div className="container">
                    
                        <h2 className="loginPage__title">Seja bem vindo!</h2>
                        <form className="loginPage__form" action="/" onSubmit={this.fazerLogin}>
                            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Login</label> 
                                <input className="loginPage__input" type="text" id="login" name="login"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="senha">Senha</label> 
                                <input className="loginPage__input" type="password" id="senha" name="senha"/>
                            </div>
                            {/* <div className="loginPage__errorBox">
                                Mensagem de erro!
                            </div> */}
                            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                <button className="loginPage__btnLogin" type="submit">
                                    Logar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        
        )
    }
    
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You are not creating and attaching the refs anywhere. Please read the ref documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs - seems that the refs are deprecated now... Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588556/shmwel

Comment: I removed the refs, but the same error persists.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're attaching the refs to the input element. Also, if you're trying to get values from an input, I'd suggest using state and an `onChange` handler rather than getting the value from a ref.